# Should I reply amen to a blessing that was said in a movie?

Tags: halacha, amen, performance-entertainment

Have you ever watched Stisel or a similar movie? Every several minutes somebody blesses over something, and usually, it is a proper blessing.

Should we answer amen to them?

Comment: Hi Ian, welcome to MY, and thank you for this great question!

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Ian and thanks for this first question. Can I recommend you take the [tour](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour) to get a sense of how the site works?  Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: relevant: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/6416/11501

Comment: Thanks for welcoming me! It is a pleasure to be part of a site like this one!

Comment: related (and provides an answer by sidestepping the point currently being argued) https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/3308/amen-for-recorded-brochos/3309

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A movie is a recording of the past, the blessing is not happening in front of you when watching the movie. It’s documentation of an event that already happened. You do not have to amen the blessing because the blessing was actualized in the past. You are not a witness to the blessing when watching a recording, you are a witness to documentation of a past blessing which is fundamentally a different event. There is a similar question/answer [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/3308/19463), noting amen are not required for prerecorded brochos.

From my limited understanding “amen” could mean “let it be” or “so be it” or “may it be so” or  essentially “please let it be as we have prayed”.

If the blessing was in the past, to add “let it be” maybe superfluous since that which is to be blessed could have transpired.

Additionally, in the context of a movie, one who says “amen” to a recording is attempting to invoke the power of God (the real God) to help in matters which were scripted by human writers. Should we not invoke God for more significant ends, such as to end the suffering of people?

Comment: Exactly my point.

Comment: So you defined the difference between two situations. Now how do you know that you have to say amen to a blessing when it happens in front of you, but not when you are watching documentation of an event that already happened?

Comment: Your answer implies that you don't answer Amen for past events, not because you are not actually in the presence of the person making the blessing. So, if you watch a live newscast or Skype someone and hear them make a bracha, you would have to answer Amen, correct?

Comment: Yes I believe so, if it was a purposeful blessing not in the context of blessing a scripted fiction.

Comment: "If the blessing was in the past, to add “let it be” maybe superfluous since that which is to be blessed could have transpired." - not valid in case of bircat hanehenin. "Additionally, in the context of a movie, one who says “amen” to a recording is attempting to invoke the power of God (the real God) to help in matters which were scripted by human writers. Should we not invoke God for more significant ends, such as to end the suffering of people?" - also does not apply to bircat hanehenin.

Answer (score -4):

No, because it is a movie and not reality, even if it is based on truth. The only exception to this rule would be a lecture by a real rabbi on tv.

Comment: This could be greatly improved by a source. Also, the OP specifically is discussing a case where “somebody blesses over something and usually it is a proper blessing,” so it not being reality is presumed false.

Comment: However, If the actor blesses on a glass of water, and drinks it, even if the story by itself was fake, the blessing was a real obligation.

Comment: @IanTrolles I tend to disagree. If it was an actor, it is an actor playing the part of an observant Jew, unless he really is observant and admits it on the special features, I would not repeat the blessing because it is a movie. Even if the story presented is true, unless the person is really making the blessing (which is hard to tell) I don’t think it matters. But if it matters to you; go ahead and say the blessing anyway.

Comment: So Rav@Turk, you hold that the brachot of non-observant Jews are invalid? How observant does one  need to be for his blessing over Chanukkah candles or his hamotzi over matzah at the seder to count?

Comment: @JoshK I would suggest two instances. 1) the person is in the process of coming back to Judaism (Jews do not convert) or 2) they are already observant. If they are secular and only preforming the act out of heritage reasons, I would think they’d be no obligation to repeat. Unless you wished to say the actual prayer itself.

Comment: @TurkHill The Rema holds that you say Amen to the Berachos of idolaters if you hear the entire Beracha

Comment: I am starting to worry that I was not clear. The question was about saying Amen, and not about quitting my obligation with the bracha, as it would be obviously impossible even if Moshe himself was in the movie, as he was not thinking about freeing others form the obrigation.

Comment: @Ian No, you were perfectly clear. This answer is just wrong.

Comment: @DonielF plz feel free to proved a “right” answer to the question if you think mine is mistaken.

Comment: I meant that politely btw.

Comment: @TurkHill If I knew whether it was yes or no I’d post an answer. What I do know, though, is that your argument is flawed, as I explained above; your conclusion may be correct, but not for this reason.

Comment: @DonielF My answer is the same as Andrew Richmond. Same conclusion.

Comment: @TurkHill Same conclusion, but not the same way of reaching that conclusion is my point. I’m not sure I fully agree with his line of reasoning either, FWIW.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96732/discussion-between-turk-hill-and-donielf).

Comment: @DonielF good point.