# Microphones on Shabbat

Tags: halacha, shabbat, technology, electricity, hearing

What is the Halacha re LISTENING to someone speaking in a microphone on Shabbat. 
For example if I walk into a room and someone is lecturing/speaking on a microphone an I permitted to listen

Comment: related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/6416/microphone-for-meggilah https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/10389/why-do-music-tapes-and-cds-warn-about-playing-on-shabbos/11901#11901

Comment: Moshe avrohom, [welcome to Mi Yodeya](//judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887), and thanks for bringing your question here! I look forward to seeing you around.

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/106542/ https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/10905/

Comment: The current answer addresses a case of a non-Jew speaking to a primarily non-Jewish audience via microphone on Shabbos. Is this what you are asking about?

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/73006/audio-recording-on-shabbat-yom-tov/92088#92088

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/12160/can-you-leave-video-chat-on-over-shabbos

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/11070/am-i-allowed-to-view-a-kotel-cam-on-shabbos

Answer (score 2):

According to those who maintain that microphones are prohibited on Shabbat (see, e.g., [Rabbi Yisrael Rosen's thorough summary of the views](http://www.zomet.org.il/eng/?CategoryID=198&ArticleID=283), cited by @mbloch [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/73006/audio-recording-on-shabbat-yom-tov/92088#92088)), it should still be permitted to "eavesdrop" on the audio of a gentile speaking to a gentile audience, based on the Talmudic principle of *ner l'echad ner l'meah* - a lamp [lit] for one [person] may illuminate for a hundred [people] ([Shabbat 122a](https://www.sefaria.org/Shabbat.122a.5?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)).  See, for example, the ruling of the [Shulchan Arukh (OC 276:2)](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.276.2?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) regarding the lighting of a lamp:

> ישראל ועכו"ם שהסיבו יחד והדליק עכו"ם נר, אם רוב עכו"ם 
>    מותר להשתמש לאורו, ואם רוב ישראל או אפילו מחצה על מחצה - אסור
>
> When a Gentile lights a candle at an assembly of Jews and gentiles; if most of those present are gentiles, one may benefit from the light of the candle. However, if most or even half of those present are Jews, it is forbidden.